# Define Size of Certain Characters in the Preamble

Tags: mnsymbol

For card suit symbols I want to use the ones in `MnSymbol`. How can I define their default size one level higher? (Not sure if I put the question correctly: Basically, if text size is normal, I want them large, etc.)

Comment: Are you speaking precisely or metaphorically?  That is, would making the symbols always, for example, 20% larger than the current size be acceptable, or must it precisely match the next text size up?

Comment: @blackened Are you using the symbols in mathmode or text?

Comment: @Steven Not the next text; so, yes, say 20% larger than the current size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't load `MnSymbol` just for the card suit symbols, because this also changes *all* the math symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolCards}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> s*[1.2] MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> s*[1.2] MnSymbolC10
  <12->   s*[1.2] MnSymbolC12}{}

\newcommand{\mndiamond}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A2}}}
\newcommand{\mnheart}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A3}}}
\newcommand{\mnspade}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A4}}}
\newcommand{\mnclub}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A5}}}

\begin{document}

x\mndiamond\mnheart\mnspade\mnclub y

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a comparison, just to show that the symbols are indeed larger:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{MnSymbol} % just for comparison

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolCards}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> s*[1.2] MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> s*[1.2] MnSymbolC10
  <12->   s*[1.2] MnSymbolC12}{}

\newcommand{\mndiamond}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A2}}}
\newcommand{\mnheart}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A3}}}
\newcommand{\mnspade}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A4}}}
\newcommand{\mnclub}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A5}}}

\begin{document}

x$\diamondsuit\heartsuit\spadesuit\clubsuit$y

x\mndiamond\mnheart\mnspade\mnclub y

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the version for using the symbol also in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolCards}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> s*[1.2] MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> s*[1.2] MnSymbolC10
  <12->   s*[1.2] MnSymbolC12}{}

\newcommand{\mndiamond}{\text{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A2}}}
\newcommand{\mnheart}{\text{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A3}}}
\newcommand{\mnspade}{\text{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A4}}}
\newcommand{\mnclub}{\text{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A5}}}

\begin{document}

$\mndiamond+\mnheart=\mnspade+\mnclub$

$A_{\mndiamond}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to accept both answers as correct? They both useful to me.

Comment: @blackened With Steven's answer the symbols won't scale in subscripts/superscripts (it's doable, of course, by adding `\text` around `\scalebox`). However, I recommend not using `MnSymbols`, unless the text font is Minion.

Answer (score 3):

Here I saved `\spadesuit` as `\svspadesuit` and then redefined the original as a 20% enlargement.  I show both for comparison, in several text sizes.

While the original, `\svspadesuit`, must be used in math mode, the redefined `\spadesuit` can be used in math or text mode.  It will not, as presently redefined, capture different mathstyles, like subscripting, etc.  If that is a requirement, perhaps the OP will let me know.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,graphicx}
\let\svspadesuit\spadesuit
\def\spadesuit{\scalebox{1.2}{$\svspadesuit$}}
\begin{document}
$\svspadesuit\spadesuit$
\Large$\svspadesuit\spadesuit$
\Huge$\svspadesuit\spadesuit$
\end{document}
```

[image]